# Get data from json and use parameter when calling them

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to get a test data from json but using parameter in calling the data ?

```
const dataCredentials = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('../fixtures/credentials.json')));
const env = process.env.ENV
```

It is getting the proper data using this:

```
const usrName = dataCredentials.dev.username
```

But I want to make the environment dynamic that is why I converted the code like below:

```
const usrName = `${dataCredentials}.${env}.username`
console.log("USER CREDENTIALS>>>>> " + usrName)
```

When I run the code, I am getting below:

> USER CREDENTIALS>>>>> [object Object].dev.portal_ff_username

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dataCredentials = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('../fixtures/credentials.json')));
const env = process.env.ENV
const usrName = dataCredentials[env].username
```

should work

Comment: I am gettting this error" Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)"

Comment: @simpleMan your `process.env.ENV` is undefined. Check if it is actually getting value from your .env

Comment: it will have a value during run time. This is the console logs for that env
ENVIRONMENT>>>>>dev

Comment: @simpleMan probably typescript linting error, try type assertion ? 
`const env = process.env.ENV as string`